# How to print a php variable to the browser's console?

Tags: php, debug, browser, script

So within administrator function.

```
echo("<script>console.log('PHP: " . $data . "');</script>");
```

It seems it doesn't insert the js script on the page.
This works from a simple PHP file, but not from Joomla.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Joomla's Web Asset Manager to insert inline scripts via PHP, like so:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

$wa = Factory::getApplication()->getDocument()->getWebAssetManager();
$wa->addInlineScript('console.log("PHP: ' . $data . '")');
```

Comment: Thanks, but the file which I want to debug looks like doesn't output anything at all. "\libraries\src\Form\Field\CalendarField.php"

Comment: Can you not just `var_dump($data)`?

Comment: Noting out. This is from "Articles: Edit - Publishing tab". Not sure, but no HTML output from CalendarField.php.